# How dark souls loads dsfix

Tags: dll

since the question bugs me a lot:

how dark souls loads dsfix?
You just copy the files into the folder and the programm loads the stuff. Did the creators of dark souls programmed something like: "look under folder XY, and load every dll you find". But then, they need to call a function in this dll ?!

I don't know anymore why i have this question or how i come up with this. After googleing this question for some weeks (tutorials on how to mod dark souls, how dsfix works) and still with 0 results, i just ask it here ^^

Comment: dll files are handled by the IDE itself, you just have to include them into the project.

EDIT: Also I cant find any programmatic mods for Dark Souls, only re-textures and aesthetic stuff. Maybe DS doesnt support mods of that kind.

Comment: It does. DSFix makes the grafic better and increase the resolution. I just want to know how they did it, that dark souls loads the dsfix.dll. Something in the programm has to say: "load dsfix.dll". But since you don't replace the exe with some other exe i just dont get it how it works ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The game's main executable 'data.exe' has `dinput8.dll` in its import table, which I suppose is one of the DirectX APIs.

When the module loader attempts to load the DLL, it first searches the directory containing the EXE for a file with that name — if it doesn't find it there, then it searches the system directory (which is where Microsoft's DLL normally resides). By having the replacement `dinput8.dll` from DSFix in the application directory, the loader picks it up instead of the standard one, allowing it to intercept particular function calls made by the game and apply the necessary corrections.

Note that this doesn't work for all DLLs. In some cases the module loader bypasses the usual search order (e.g. for `user32.dll`). In other cases the application itself may override the search order.